# C - program writes only one line with fprintf

Tags: c, file, printf

I am trying to create a program that writes a file with different threads. I have written the following code.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


pthread_t thread_id;

void *write_file(void *arg) {
    int number = (int) arg;
    FILE *file_write = fopen("file.txt", "w");
    fprintf(file_write, "Number: %d\n", number);
    fclose(file_write);
    printf("Thread Finalized\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    chdir("/");
    srand(time(NULL));
    int cont = 0;
    while(1) {
        int random_number = rand();
        if(random_number % 5 == 0) {
            cont++;
            int response = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, write_file, (void *) random_number);
            if(response != 0) {
                printf("Can't create process\n");
            } else {
                printf("Thread created successfully\n");
            }
        }
        sleep(1); 
        if(cont == 8) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But when I open the file I find that has only one line as follows:

```
Number: 1069822935
```

What I expect is that the file should contain 8 lines with random numbers divisible by 5.

Thank you.

Comment: When you open with `w` mode it empties the file. If you want to add to the file, use `a` mode.

Comment: It is important to notice that if you want to execute the file you must have a `file.txt` in the root (`/`) directory.

Comment: After you've fixed your `fopen` problem, your next task is much more advanced. You're going to need to prevent those threads from stepping all over each other. Your file will end up randomly garbled if you don't.

Comment: Thank you @CareyGregory for de advice, for now, I don't need to deal with concurrency while the method is accessing the file. But I will take this issue into account and I will try to control this lack as exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file mode cannot work like that. If each thread opens the file in "w" - write - each will overwrite whatever was there already. "a" for append should work.

see also: http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-file-open-modes/

Answer (score 2):

With `"w"`, each call to `fopen` truncates the file. So they each write starting from the beginning. You should open the file in append mode… Then you will run into concurrency issues ;-)